# Why is AsynchResult stored in System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging in the .NET framework?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Just out of curiosity, does anyone know why the AsynchResult type resides in System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging as opposed to System.Threading ?  It would seem to make more sense to have it declared with all threading types.

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's just one concrete implementation of the [`System.IAsyncResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.aspx) interface, and it happens to be an implementation that is used for remoting calls.  You can use it elsewhere, but that's not what it's intended for.

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling this particular class is there as one of the concrete implementations of [IAsyncResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.aspx) and  [IMessageSink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.imessagesink.aspx) interfaces, which is in System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging itself.

Answer (score 2):

A fundamental capability that Remoting has is to be able to create a stack frame in another execution context and make a method call.  Exactly what is needed to marshal a method call from one thread to another.  This is quite non-trivial btw but very well hidden.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: Asynchrony can be achieved in more ways that through the use of threads: inter-process communication or inter machine communication immediately come to mind. Messaging is a more generalized abstraction of communication between computational units that do not operate in synchronous lock-step than is threading.